# DataBase Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, database

```
echo $column;//Here $column="Date ,1007001 ,1007002 ,1007003 ,1007004 ,1007005 ,1007006";
echo $columnvalue; // Here $columnvalue="'12/27/2012' ,'1' ,'0' ,'1' ,'1' ,'0' ,'1'" ;
$sql_cmd ="INSERT INTO `databasename`.`$table` (`$column`) VALUES ($columnvalue)"; 
if(!mysql_query($sql_cmd)) {
       die('inside AddUserToDataBase Error: ' . mysql_error());
       }
```

Here I got the error:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
How to fixed it?
Please help.

Comment: you're giving `$column`, which is putting one back tick around all of the values in $column. you should have the back ticks inside of each column name in $column, instead of surrounding a backtick in the query.

Comment: Learn about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

('$column') should be ($column)
('$column') means the column name

```
('Date ,1007001 ,1007002 ,1007003 ,1007004 ,1007005 ,1007006')
```

And that is basically 1 column with a strange name (the name is 'Date ,1007001 ,1007002 ,1007003 ,1007004 ,1007005 ,1007006' ) and it should either be

```
(Date ,1007001 ,1007002 ,1007003 ,1007004 ,1007005 ,1007006)
```

or

```
('Date' ,'1007001' ,'1007002' ,'1007003' ,'1007004' ,'1007005' ,'1007006')
```

Comment: Also I do not think it is good practice to call a column Date. That is a MySQL keyword and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

usually occurs when your columns defined in the values clause don't match your actual table columns.

say your table has 4 coulmns, col1 col2 col3 col4

and you want to only insert data into col2, col3, col4

Your insert statement should be:

`Insert into table (col2, col3, col4) values (col2val, col3val, col4val)`